# Debian 9 stretch Linux.mysql issue

Tags: mysql

Running on Debian 9 stretch Linux.

MariaDB [(none)]> USE mysql;
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'mysql'

this is my issue

Have mysql-server installed

Comment: Looks like you don't know your main DB name. It can be anything.

Comment: What do you get from `SHOW DATABASES;`

Answer (score 0):

Check /var/lib/mysql for a mysql subfolder. If it's not there, the default mysql db might have not been created. If that's the case, create the mysql subfolder then restart mysql service.